# Parse KOI8-r encoding objective c

Tags: objective-c, url, encoding, url-parsing

I need to parse url which is actually in KOI8-R encoding and as i've surfed there is no encoding in objective c which allows to do that.

It used to be smth like this
  NSString* fileText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"ThePageISurf.com"] 
                                                  encoding: **NSCyrrilicKOI8-Rencoding**                                           error:nil];

Maybe there is a library/method to convert string to KOI8-R? Or Even URL directly?
There is got to be the way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingKOI8_R)`.

Comment: Thnx this was sooo helpful (Got the string just in format i wanted by  directly reading to string from url)!  NSString* fileText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"TheDudesPage.com"] 
                                                  encoding: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingKOI8_R)                                             error:nil];